# Scroll in Struts2

Tags: css, jsp, struts2

I want to create the div with more textfiled:

```
<s:div cssClass="div_position">
  <s:textfield  cssClass="position" id="position1" value=""  name="position1" ></s:textfield>
  <s:textfield  cssClass="position" id="position2" value=""  name="position2" ></s:textfield>
  <s:textfield  cssClass="position" id="position3" value=""  name="position3" ></s:textfield>
  <s:textfield  cssClass="position" id="position4" value=""  name="position4" ></s:textfield>
  <s:textfield  cssClass="position" id="position5" value=""  name="position5" ></s:textfield>
</s:div>
```

The class "div_position" is the follow:

```
.div_position{ height:50px; overflow-y:Scroll; }
```

It doesn't work, I only display the textfields but outside the div.
Someone can help me.

Comment: You need to post your "position" class applied to every div. The problem is there. And use "scroll" instead of "Scroll"

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
 <s:div cssClass="div_position" cssStyle="height:50px;overflow-y:scroll;">
<s:textfield  cssClass="position" id="position1" value=""  name="position1" ></s:textfield>
<s:textfield  cssClass="position" id="position2" value=""  name="position2" ></s:textfield><br>
<s:textfield  cssClass="position" id="position3" value=""  name="position3" ></s:textfield>
<s:textfield  cssClass="position" id="position4" value=""  name="position4" ></s:textfield><br>
<s:textfield  cssClass="position" id="position5" value=""  name="position5" ></s:textfield>
</s:div>
```

because I have configured the `simple` theme. Do it like me put this in the `struts.xml`

```
<constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"/>
```

Comment: I copied your code but i don't display the scroll in the div...;(

Comment: I have this div inside the form...it could be a problem?

Comment: @user2273574 What theme are you using?

Comment: @user2273574 No, it's just css feature, I was sure that the `style` attribute overrides the style used for this tag. I don't understand why struts overrides my style.

Comment: I have this in my struts.xml:  <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />

Comment: @user2273574 It dosn't matter use the constant in the answer (updated) or use `<div` tag instead of `s:div` or create your own theme that doesn't override the style.

Comment: how can i create the  theme?