# How to disable label of <s:textfield> tag in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I have the following tag in struts2:

```
<s:textfield type="text" key="maquina" label="" labelSeparator="" style="width:100;"/>
```

and I want to disable the label by this tag, is this moment in my html code is generated as shown below:

```
   <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>

            <th>Hora</th>
            <th>Ruta</th>
            <th>Maquina</th>


        </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        <%int i=10;%>
        <s:iterator value="datosPlan" var="datosPlanLoading" status="valorDatosPlan">

            <%--//cambia de color la fila en la que se encuentra le cursor--%>
            <tr id="<%=i%>"
                    <%
                        if(i%2 == 0)
                        {
                    %>
                class="alt"
                style="background: #E1EEf4;color: #00557F;"
                onmouseover="destacarFila(this.id);"
                onmouseout="colorOriginalFila(this.id,0);"
                    <%
                    }
                    else
                    {   %>
                onmouseover="destacarFila(this.id);"
                onmouseout="colorOriginalFila(this.id,1);"
                    <%
                        }
                        i++;
                    %>
                    >
                <%--<input type="hidden" id="<%="editar"%>${listaHorariosLoading.codigoHorario}" value="${listaHorariosLoading.nombreHorario}">--%>

                 <td>
                    <p>
                        <s:property value="hora"/>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                        <s:property value="ruta"/>
                    </p>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p>
                       <s:textfield type="text" name="maquina" style="width:100;"/>
                    </p>
                </td>

            </tr>

        </s:iterator>
        </tbody>
```

therefore I want to disable label because I want to just the input type.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `key="maquina"` then it will generate label for you.

If you use `label=""` then it will generate label for you.

**Don't** use `key` and also do not use `label` attributes.

Try this

```
 <s:textfield type="text" id="maquina" name="maquina" style="width:20;" />
```

**Output:**

```
 <input id="maquina" type="text" style="width:20;" value="" name="maquina">
 </input>
```

**EDIT :**

`<td class="tdLabel"></td>` will be generated if you use `<s:form>`

Try to use html form tag `<form>` instead of `<s:form>`.

**For Example**

```
 <form action="someAction" method="get" >
  <s:textfield type="text" id="maquina" name="maquina" style="width:20;" />
 </form>
```

**Note:**

And if you want to use  tag then you need to implement either template in freemarker or custom theme.

[Tutorial 1](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/working-with-struts-2-theme-template/)
[Tutorial 2](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_themes_templates.htm)

In `struts.xml`

```
 <constant name="struts.ui.theme" value="simple"/>
```

will also remove default template.

Comment: with the name attribute my generated code is:<tr>
    <td class="tdLabel"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="maquina" value="" id="maquina" style="width:100;"></td>
</tr>

Comment: ohh.. so you want to remove `<td class="tdLabel"></td>`. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know why thats happens, but mi code is inside of a table, I going to edit my questions by you can see the table

Comment: You `tr`'s are generating because of `<s:form>` tag. Try to convert `s:form` to `html` form. Do not use struts form tag, instead use simple html form tag

Comment: I did this <input type="text" value="${maquina}"/> and it's works

Comment: I actually advised you to not to use `<s:form>` tag. you can use `<s:textfield>`.. check I edited the answer. yes you can also use `<input>`

Comment: Your table must be surrounded by form tag.. show it

Answer (score 2):

> because I want to just the input type

This is only possible if you use [`simple` theme](https://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/themes-and-templates) configured to be used by the tag.

Comment: but where I can config that.

Comment: You can config that using struts config `constant` tag. You can also change the `default` theme using `theme` tag's attribute. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16384925/573032